# For Loop in Windows Command Line

Tags: command-line, window

How to get make this loop working:

```
set list=am gp it ol

 FOR %%a IN (%list%) DO (   
     set Indxed= %%a
     ECHO %Indxed%             

)
```

Echo always output to :ol ol ol ol. How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set list=am gp it ol

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ("%list%") DO (
   set Indxed=%%a
   ECHO !Indxed!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try following:**

```
@echo off
setlocal

set list=am gp it ol

echo %list%

call :parse "%list%"

goto :eos

:parse

set list=%1
set list=%list:"=%

FOR /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%a IN ("%list%") DO (
  if not "%%a" == "" call :sub %%a
  if not "%%b" == "" call :parse "%%b"
)

goto :eos

:sub

echo %1

goto :eos

:eos
endlocal
```